# How to monitor progress of an apply function?

Tags: r, data.table, apply

I need to work out a 2886*2886 correlation matrix, problem is that building an intermediary datatable (`RESULT`) takes a long time for it to be binded together so I would like to be able to do the following things while calling the last line `RESULT=rbindlist(apply(COMB, 1, append))` in the code below :

1. Estimate the time it will take for the apply function to complete
2. Monitor its progress
3. Be able to pause and continue at later time

Here is the code :

```
SOURCE=data.table(NAME=rep(paste0("NAME", as.character(1:2889)), each=600), VALUE=sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), 600, TRUE) )
> SOURCE
            NAME VALUE
      1:   NAME1  TRUE
      2:   NAME1  TRUE
      3:   NAME1  TRUE
      4:   NAME1  TRUE
      5:   NAME1  TRUE
     ---              
1733396: NAME999  TRUE
1733397: NAME999  TRUE
1733398: NAME999  TRUE
1733399: NAME999  TRUE
1733400: NAME999 FALSE

setkey(SOURCE,NAME)
a=SOURCE[,unique(NAME)]
COMB=data.table(expand.grid(a,a, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
> COMB
             Var1    Var2
      1:    NAME1   NAME1
      2:   NAME10   NAME1
      3:  NAME100   NAME1
      4: NAME1000   NAME1
      5: NAME1001   NAME1
     ---                 
8346317:  NAME995 NAME999
8346318:  NAME996 NAME999
8346319:  NAME997 NAME999
8346320:  NAME998 NAME999
8346321:  NAME999 NAME999

append <- function(X) {
data.table(NAME1=X[1], VALUE1=SOURCE[X[1], VALUE], 
    NAME2=X[2], VALUE2=SOURCE[X[2], VALUE] )
}

RESULT=rbindlist(apply(COMB, 1, append))
```

Any idea ?

Also do you know if there is a faster way to generate the datatable `RESULT` from  `SOURCE` ? `RESULT`is an intermediary datatable to work out the correlation values between `VALUE1` and `VALUE2` for each couple of `NAME`.

With a subset of `SOURCE` `RESULT`looks like that :

```
SOURCE=SOURCE[sample(1:nrow(SOURCE), 3)]
setkey(SOURCE,NAME)
a=SOURCE[,unique(NAME)]
COMB=data.table(expand.grid(a,a, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
RESULT=rbindlist(apply(COMB, 1, append))
> RESULT
      NAME1 VALUE1    NAME2 VALUE2
1: NAME1859   TRUE NAME1859   TRUE
2:  NAME768  FALSE NAME1859   TRUE
3:  NAME795   TRUE NAME1859   TRUE
4: NAME1859   TRUE  NAME768  FALSE
5:  NAME768  FALSE  NAME768  FALSE
6:  NAME795   TRUE  NAME768  FALSE
7: NAME1859   TRUE  NAME795   TRUE
8:  NAME768  FALSE  NAME795   TRUE
9:  NAME795   TRUE  NAME795   TRUE
```

Later on I'm going to do `RESULT[,VALUE3:=(VALUE1==VALUE2)]` to finally get the correlation values : `RESULT[, mean(VALUE3), by=c("NAME1", "NAME2")]`
So maybe the whole process can be done more efficiently, who knows.

Comment: For progress I often add a line at the start of a function, e.g.
`lapply(1:nrow(f), function(i){` `print(i/nrow(f)` `# your function` `})`

Answer (score 30):

You can use the library `pbapply`([git](https://github.com/psolymos/pbapply)), which shows a time estimate and a progress bar to any function in the '*apply' family.

In the case of your question:

```
library(pbapply)      
library(data.table)      

result <- data.table::rbindlist( pbapply(COMB, 1, append) )
```

ps. This answer solves your two initial points. Regarding the third point, I'm not sure if it's possible to pause the function. In any case, your operation is indeed taking too long, so I would recommend you post a separate question asking how to optimize your task.

Comment: It says it's not available for R version 3.0.3

Comment: They should update the package any time soon. In the mean time, you can use R version 3.2.5

Comment: `Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘‘pbapply’ is not available (for R version 3.2.5)` tried 3.3.0 too

Comment: Try `library(devtools) ; install_github("psolymos/pbapply")`. If it still doesn't work, you can report a bug at the [github page](https://github.com/psolymos/pbapply).

Comment: FYI: `pbapply` is now available on CRAN.

Comment: I didn't know about this tool and It's great. However has anybody try benchmark of pbapply vs lapply with huge data ?

Comment: This is great! Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

You can use `txtProgressBar` from the `utils` package:

```r
total <- 50
pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = total, style = 3)

lapply(1:total, function(i){
Sys.sleep(0.1)
setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
})
```

OR use `*ply` family from `plyr` package

```
library(plyr)
laply(1:100, function(i) {Sys.sleep(0.05); i}, .progress = "text")
```

Check `?create_progress_bar()` for more details

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
setkey(SOURCE, NAME)

SOURCE[, CJ(NAME, NAME, unique = T)][
       , mean(SOURCE[V1, VALUE] == SOURCE[V2, VALUE]), by = .(V1, V2)]
```

Fwiw, the all-caps names are an awful choice imo - makes writing and reading code significantly harder.

Comment: thanks for the better way of doing this, but is there a way to monitor its progress ?

Comment: @ChiseledAbs I'd simply insert a print statement (perhaps with some frequency); e.g. for the above: `..., {print(paste(V1, V2)); mean(SOURCE[... )}, by = .(V1, V2)]`

Comment: When I try your code I get `Error in bmerge(i <- shallow(i), x, leftcols, rightcols, io <- haskey(i),  : 
  typeof x.VALUE (logical) != typeof i.V1 (character)`

Comment: @ChiseledAbs had a typo in the answer - try again

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do a cross-join? See this example:

```
#dummy data
set.seed(1)
SOURCE = data.frame(
  NAME = sample(paste0("Name", 1:4),20, replace = TRUE),
  VALUE = sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), 20, replace = TRUE)
)

#update colnames for join
d1 <- SOURCE
colnames(d1) <- c("NAME1", "VALUE1")
d2 <- SOURCE
colnames(d2) <- c("NAME2", "VALUE2")

#cross join
merge(d1, d2, all = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote my own implementation of a text progress line. I didn't know about [`txtProgressBar()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/txtProgressBar.html), so thanks to @JavK for that! But I'll still share my implementation here.

---

I learnt something very useful while working on this problem. I was originally planning on depending on [terminfo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminfo) for cursor control. Specifically, I was going to precompute the current terminal's code to move the cursor left using `tput`:

```
tc_left <- system2('tput','cub1',stdout=T);
```

And then I was going to repeatedly print that code to reset the cursor to the start of the progress line after every update. This solution works, but only in Unix terminals that have a proper terminfo database installed; it will not work on other platforms, most notably RStudio on Windows.

Then when I looked into the `txtProgressBar()` code (after reading @JavK's answer), I discovered they use a much simpler and more robust solution to reset the cursor position: they simply print a carriage return! It's as simple as `cat('\r');`, which is what I am now using in my implementation.

---

Here's my solution. It involves one initialization function called `progInit()` which you must call once prior to the computationally intensive loop, and to which you must pass the total number of iterations of the loop (which you therefore must know in advance), and one update function called `prog()` which increments a loop counter and updates the progress line. State variables are simply dumped into the global environment under names beginning with `prog`.

```
progInit <- function(N,dec=3L) {
    progStart <<- Sys.time();
    progI <<- 1L;
    progN <<- N;
    progDec <<- dec;
}; ## end progInit()

prog <- function() {
    rem <- unclass(difftime(Sys.time(),progStart,units='secs'))*(progN/progI-1);
    days <- as.integer(rem/86400); rem <- rem-days*86400;
    hours <- as.integer(rem/3600); rem <- rem-hours*3600;
    minutes <- as.integer(rem/60); rem <- rem-minutes*60;
    seconds <- as.integer(rem); rem <- rem-seconds;
    millis <- as.integer(rem*1000);
    over <- paste(collapse='',rep(' ',20L));
    pct <- progI/progN*100;
    if (days!=0L) {
        msg <- sprintf(' %.*f%% %dd/%02d:%02d:%02d.%03d%s',
            progDec,pct,days,hours,minutes,seconds,millis,over);
    } else {
        msg <- sprintf(' %.*f%% %02d:%02d:%02d.%03d%s',
            progDec,pct,hours,minutes,seconds,millis,over);
    }; ## end if
    cat('\r');
    cat(msg);
    cat('\r');
    progI <<- progI+1L;
}; ## end prog()
```

---

```
library(data.table);
SOURCE <- data.table(NAME=rep(paste0("NAME", as.character(1:2889)), each=600), VALUE=sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), 600, TRUE) );
setkey(SOURCE,NAME);
a <- SOURCE[,unique(NAME)];
COMB <- data.table(expand.grid(a,a, stringsAsFactors=FALSE));
append <- function(X) {
    prog();
    data.table(NAME1=X[1],VALUE1=SOURCE[X[1],VALUE],NAME2=X[2],VALUE2=SOURCE[X[2],VALUE]);
}; ## end append()
##x <- COMB; progInit(nrow(x)); rbindlist(apply(x,1,append)); ## full object
x <- COMB[1:1e4,]; progInit(nrow(x)); rbindlist(apply(x,1,append)); ## ~30s
```

---

I use a simple algorithm to estimate the remaining time: I basically take the total elapsed time divided by the number of iterations completed so far (to get time/iteration), and then multiply that by the number of remaining iterations.

Unfortunately, when I run the code on your full `COMB` object, the estimate behaves erratically; first it drops rapidly, then it rises steadily. This seems to be caused by a slowdown in the speed of processing, which I can't explain, and I'm not sure if you see the same thing. In any case, theoretically, if you wait for the loop to get closer to completion, the increase in estimated remaining time should reverse, and eventually the estimate should fall to zero as the computation reaches completion. But despite this quirk, I'm quite confident the code is correct, since it works as expected for faster (i.e. less computationally intensive) test cases.

Answer (score 0):

For fancy progress bars (not in base/standard library), there also is [`progress`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=progress):

```r
pb <- progress_bar$new(
  format = "  downloading [:bar] :percent eta: :eta",
  total = 100, clear = FALSE, width= 60)
for (i in 1:100) {
  pb$tick()
  Sys.sleep(1 / 100)
}

#> downloading [========----------------------]  28% eta:  1s
```

So this fulfills requirements (1) and (2), not (3) though. For caching intermediate results, it's probably easiest to write stuff to disk every now and then. For fast serialization you could try

- [`fst`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=fst): convenient for serializing columnar data structures such as `data.tables`
- [`qs`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=qs) for more general object serialization

I hope this helps.